# Does HTML include the parsed CSS result as inline styling?

Tags: html, css, parsing, dom

I am learning a little more about the DOM right now and I have a question please.

when the CSS has finished parsing then the CSS is combined again with the HTML. Are the css rules at this point then actually applied as inline style? like:

```
<div style="background: red; ..."></div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you asking if, when the HTML is parsed that all of the CSS rules are inserted as an inline style? If so, that is definitely not the case.

Comment: The CSS rules are not combined with the HTML. They're applied to the DOM objects where they appear as part of the computed styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** They are applied onto DOM nodes, but it does not literally insert a `style` attribute on any tag that is affected by CSS. However, some automated ways of styling the DOM through JavaScript/jQuery may involve writing to `style` attributes directly.